# Are BT MAC addresses of devices requesting BT connections to the Mac logged in High Sierra?

Tags: bluetooth, high-sierra, logs, console

A neighbor of mine has a phone that keeps trying to connect to my Mac. Considering they're probably trying to connect, I'm a little annoyed.

Any way I can find the BT MAC logged anywhere by default in High Sierra so I can pop this into the IgnoredDevices array?

My console digging hasn't helped me so far.

Comment: I'm more concerned that your Mac is continually in "discoverable" mode.  Check your paired devices and make sure you have never connected to them before.

Comment: Yes, all Macs are always in discoverable mode, AFAICT. I don't know when Apple took away the discoverable mode switch, but it doesn't exist anymore. Regardless, what I need is a log file. I've already checked my connected devices.

Comment: I don't think so.  I am on my iMac right now typing on a BT keyboard and just scanned for devices using my iPhone.  It doesn't show up as discoverable. However, when I launch BT preferences, it becomes discoverable as expected.

Comment: I don't know how to post a picture to a message here, but holding option while clicking on the BT menubar icon shows me that, according to my Mac, discoverable is OFF when the Bluetooth system preferences pane is not open, and ON when it is. This Mac is functioning normally, and you're right that it's not normally in discoverable mode.

Comment: Also one other thing I discovered is that com.apple.Bluetooth.plist logs the MAC of the things that request connection even if they don't get connected, which is a little weird. Anyway, I found two MAC addresses for the same  types of phones, one of which resolves to Sony and the other one of which no database recognizes. Regardless, I can put them both in IgnoredDevices now.